# A website is collection many webapplications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, page-lifecycle

I just heard a very experienced .NET instructor say that a website is a collection of many webapplications and for every webapplication there is a AppDomain.

Does webapplication in this context mean webforms?

Comment: Can you reference what you're asking about with a website?  I would think of a website as (potentially) many services, and services can be made up of problem domains, if you're thinking in a domain driven design aspect.  Otherwise, I'm as little unclear on what you're asking.

Comment: @Kritner this in context of asp.net page life cycle. 
https://youtu.be/hzSAYjRm-r0?t=1035

Comment: You can load web applications as "folders" in an IIS website but that is uncommon and a bad idea because the web.config settings interact.

Answer (score 3):

In IIS, a "Web Site" is what is tied to a specific host name and port. That web site can contain one or more "Web Applications", which is what can be created in ASP.NET. Each "Web application" is isolated from the others and contains it's own global.asax, sessions etc.

The isolation is not total though, web.config settings are inherited to sub directories. Applications sharing the same app pool can interfer with each other (the sandboxing is not perfect)

Answer (score 0):

A website consists of one or more projects (one could say webapplications, however I think that is confusing terminology), each getting compiled to an assembly. Before the code in an assembly can be run it needs to be loaded into an application domain (AppDomain), which is an isolated piece of memory in which the code will run.